# How to display a timetable for reservable resources?

Tags: theming

Is there a module that will allow me to display a timetable in a grid similar to the attached image?

Rooms are vocabulary terms, and each of the time blocks (e.g. Elementary, Junior) are nodes of a specific content type (Time Block) which contain a starting and ending time (date field) and the term reference field pointing to the room name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use any of below modules :

1. [Field TimeTable](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_timetable)

> A Fields module that creates a timetable field that can be display
>   through an nice weekly grid. Can be use to display opening hours or
>   working hours in a very neat way.
>
> If you need to display office hours in a graphical way you have now a
>   proper solution !

2. [Grid Field Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/grid_field_formatter)

> the Grid Field Formatter module provides a simple way to overridde the
>   display of multi-value fields to show as a grid/table with a certain
>   number of columns.